# How can I make this jQuery code leaner, meaner and cleaner

Tags: jquery, optimization

I've currently got a load of jQuery functions for a site I'm currently front-ending on. I'm not really a jQuery 'ninja' (I have finally started reading the sitepoint book though) so I'm sure this code is probably badly written and could be a little cleaner, meaner and leaner.

Here's the code -

```
// add hasJS to html to allow for CSS fallbacks

jQuery(function($) {
$('html').addClass('hasJS');
});

// ENDS

// show/hide/kill the upload files modal box 

$('.upload').click(function(){
$('.uploader').toggle();
});

$('.creategroup').click(function(){
$('.createnewgroup').toggle();
return false;  
});

$('.adduser').click(function(){
$('.addnewuser').toggle();
return false;
});

 $('#tap-menu').click(function() {
$('#left-column, #settings, #ortibi, #userprofile').toggle();
 }); 

$('.cancel').click(function(){
$('.uploader, .shareform').hide();
  });

$('.connection-type').click(function(){
$('.connectform').toggle();
  });


$('.shareit').click(function(){
$('.shareform').show();
});
$(function() {
    $('article .folder-items').hide();    

$("p.folder").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().next(".folder-items").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();

});


// ENDS

$('textarea#txtarea_Message"').autoResize({
// On resize:
onResize : function() {
    $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
},
// After resize:
animateCallback : function() {
    $(this).css({opacity:1});
},
// Quite slow animation:
animateDuration : 300,
// More extra space:
extraSpace : 40
});

$("input:checkbox").uniform();
$("#check1").live("click", function(){
var two = $("#check2").attr("checked", this.checked);
$.uniform.update(two);
});
```

Now I'm probably doing a lot wrong here. What can I do to improve this code? All help appreciated :o)

Comment: Doesn't look that wrong to me.

Comment: That looks pretty good to me!

Comment: This is really pretty basic things you're doing. I think you're on the right track in terms of breaking things down into components. You have your handlers in place to swap your classes so you can test your UI, then you can move onto the actual business logic and implementing what actually happens in the backend. My strong suggestion for you is to think of much more specific questions that you can ask here. This is clearly way too general for Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Only thing that catches my eye is it appears as though you have three separate "document ready" scripts.  Perhaps everything should be put into separate functions then called in the document.ready. I could be wrong but isn't $(document).ready, jquery(function(), and $(function() all the same?

Comment: It would be interesting to see you html. Maybe you can improve your selector usage or use event delegation to improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
// add hasJS to html to allow for CSS fallbacks
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('html').addClass('hasJS');

    $('article .folder-items').hide();
    $("p.folder").click(function () { $(this).parent().next(".folder-items").slideToggle("slow"); });

    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
});

// ENDS

// show/hide/kill the upload files modal box

$('.upload').click(function () { $('.uploader').toggle(); });

$('.creategroup').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $('.createnewgroup').toggle(); });

$('.adduser').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $('.addnewuser').toggle(); });

$('#tap-menu').click(function () { $('#left-column, #settings, #ortibi, #userprofile').toggle(); });

$('.cancel').click(function () { $('.uploader, .shareform').hide(); });

$('.connection-type').click(function () { $('.connectform').toggle(); });

$('.shareit').click(function () { $('.shareform').show(); });

$('textarea#txtarea_Message"').autoResize({
    // On resize:
    onResize: function () { $(this).css({ opacity: 0.8 }); },
    // After resize:
    animateCallback: function () { $(this).css({ opacity: 1 }); },
    // Quite slow animation:
    animateDuration: 300,
    // More extra space:
    extraSpace: 40
});

$("input:checkbox").uniform();
$("#check1").bind("click", function () {
    var two = $("#check2").attr("checked", this.checked);
    $.uniform.update(two);
});
```

Comment: The e.preventDefault(); is key.  Especially if .adduser / .creategroup are links and not buttons.

Answer (score 1):

1. Jquery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of version 1.7, [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
   works/performs better
2. As JT Smith commented - you have multiple 'document ready'
   scripts in mutiple formats -

   You can wrap all those into one on 'document ready' call

   `$(document).ready{function() {} }`, `jquery(function() { }`, and
   `$(function() { }`  - AFAIK all these are same and work the same. You
   could stick to a single format.